# Scrapy selectors work in shell, but don't work in spider

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

For some reason, my Scrapy selectors work in Shell, but they don't work in Spider.

Code is below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class BookingParserSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "booking_parser"
    start_urls = ["https://www.booking.com/searchresults.hr.html?dest_id=-73785;dest_type=city;ss=Adamovec"]

    def parse(self, response):
        listing_selector = response.xpath("//div[@class='sr_property_block_main_row']")

        for listing in listing_selector:

            listing_name_selector = ".//a[@class='hotel_name_link url']/span/text()"

            yield {
                "bookingName": listing.xpath(listing_name_selector).extract_first()
            }
```

Here is the Scrapy log:

```
2020-05-18 20:00:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-05-18 20:00:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-05-18 20:00:40 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-05-18 20:00:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.booking.com/searchresults.hr.html?dest_id=-73785;dest_type=city;ss=Adamovec> (referer: None)
2020-05-18 20:00:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-05-18 20:00:41 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 278,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 165814,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.394505,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 18, 18, 0, 41, 412600),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 18, 18, 0, 40, 18095)}
2020-05-18 20:00:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

When I try it in Shell, it works, here:

```
>>> response.xpath("//a[@class='hotel_name_link url']/span/text()").extract_first()
'\nKuća za odmor Bajtica\n'
```

I have tried I believe almost every possible XPath combination there is. Is it perhaps the thing in proxies or in the starting URL (ie. Is booking somehow blocking me?).

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you are working with different versions of scrapy. Just a guess

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? I am using latest version of Scrapy. `(venv) C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\TheHeadacheProject\booking>scrapy crawl booking_parser
2020-05-18 20:00:39 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: booking)
2020-05-18 20:00:39 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1
g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0`

Comment: try printing ```listing_selector``` pretty sure, that's empty.

Comment: Ah thank you, you pointed me in the right direction. `//div[@class='sr-hotel__title-wrap']` is the correct selector.

Comment: You are welcome!